# PHP - IE doesn't display updated values from database. Chrome, FF, Opera - OK

Tags: php, mysql, internet-explorer

I'm working on a system that treats student course requests and teachers submit answers on those requests. There's a listbox that contains new requests, when clicked on an option item in the listbox, request_id (listbox.this.value) is querying the database via AJAX and query results are displayed back on client - student info etc. The teacher simply types his answer in an designated field and there's an update query that updates the database with an answer. But when later I click on the same item in the listbox - all the data displayed (student info) except of the updated info (teacher's answer). Again - it only occurs with IE. All rest of the browsers are fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using jQuery for the ajax requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that IE is caching the response to the initial AJAX request.  You can try appending a timestamp to the request as a GET parameter which will force IE to issue a new request.

Comment: like a glove! :) thanks for leading me in the right direction! indeed - Microsoft just HAS to be different! it's the caching problem solved by adding &dummy_time="+new Date().getTime()+"",true); to GET parameters. Is there any way to do it globally and not for every AJAX request? It's not JQuery so cache:false is not an option for me...

Comment: Depending on how you implemented your native AJAX calls, possibly, but without knowing that it's hard to tell.  For instance, if you pass all of your calls through an AJAX object that you constructed, you could append the GET parameters in there.  If not, it may be a bit more difficult

Answer (score 1):

If in some browsers you get results, and on IE you dont its not server side /php/ problem. I think you have the well known issues with IE and ajax /speccialy XMLHttpRequests/
Just look at the IE version, google the problem and you will get the solution. 
PS: Use when possible jquery ;-)