# IE caches the JSON result even though random value is added to php request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

This approach is working with JS/AJAX/PHP/JSON but when once I converted my requests to JQuery - IE started caching the result again... The scenario is when a user changes select options in a listbox (my_lstbx) there's a call to php/ajax and results come back within an array.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my_lstbx').change(function() {
        $.getJSON('Code/my_details.php'+'?'+'Math.round(new Date().getTime())', {request_id:this.value}, function(response) {
         .......
          ........
           .........
```

this is the JS version that I previously asked and it's working - [PHP - IE doesn't display updated values from database. Chrome, FF, Opera - OK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616202/php-ie-doesnt-display-updated-values-from-database-chrome-ff-opera-ok)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing `Math.round(new Date().getTime())` as a string! :D it wont get executed but will always be the same.

Change to:

```
$.getJSON('Code/my_details.php?' + new Date().getTime(), {request_id:this.value}, function(response) {
```

Comment: LOL!!! haven't noticed! thanks a bunch man! removed the '', now it's working.
BTW - why pointless? @Rocket ?

Comment: `Math.round` rounds a decimal number to it's nearest integer, `getTime` returns an integer (no decimals). So there is nothing to round.

Comment: @EricPeters: `.getTime` returns an int, so `Math.round()` just returns the exact same value.

Comment: You could also use `... .php?' + $.now(), ...`